# Make [microsoft-surface] & [surface-tablet] a synonym of [surface]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tag [microsoft-surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) is current a synonym of [pixelsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixelsense), I propese that it should instead be a synonym of [surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface) which acording to the tag description seems a much better match.

It also appears that [surface-tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface-tablet) is a little used duplicate of [surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface) and should be turned into a synonym.

---

### The stats:

- [pixelsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixelsense) (38 followers, 323 questions)

  > Microsoft PixelSense is a large-touchscreen computer platform released by Microsoft in 2008.  Applications for PixelSense are developed in .NET using either WPF or XNA for the graphical interfaces.
- [surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface) (36 followers, 506 questions)

  > Microsoft Surface is a series of tablets designed and marketed by Microsoft.
- [surface-tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface-tablet) (0 followers, 2 questions)

  > No tag description.

Comment: An alternative could be to rename the [tag:surface] tag to [tag:microsoft-surface] as a lot of the questions tagged with [surface] are done so incorrectly

Comment: In addition to @Gilles's answer.... I bought a Surface tablet when they first came out. I was having trouble porting C and C++ libraries under Visual Studio, so [I asked some questions on Microsoft's site under the Surface forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b61c2eda-410e-4c65-9a60-b9e0a8ea11b2/windows-surface-sdk-setup-and-development-on-the-tablet-windows-rt?forum=surfaceappdevelopment). I was subsequently run off because [Surface is an API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx), and the group does not refer to the Surface (or Surface Pro) tablets.

Comment: Here's the link to the [Surface Application Design and Development Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=surfaceappdevelopment) for the API.

Comment: I second this as I am writing this comment from a Surface tablet.

Comment: I foresee this discussion coming back alive once the Surface Mini is out and then we will be debating the merits of the `surface-mini` tag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The meaning of [surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface) is far from limited to the Microsoft Surface tablet. It was created a [long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391673/interpolate-a-terrain-surface-from-scattered-data-using-heat-equation) with the naive meaning in geometry and is still used for that purpose. The geometry meaning was established long before tag wikis existed.

[microsoft-surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) is currently about a different  Microsoft technology, which is now known as [pixelsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixelsense). The tag [surface-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface-rt) is unambiguously about the ARM version of the tablet.

I believe that the name Surface in reference to Microsoft evokes the Surface tablets far more often than what is now known as Pixelsense. Hence [microsoft-surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) should be unsynonymized from [pixelsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixelsense).

Given that Surface is a brand name rather than a technical designation — in particular, there are ARM and x86 versions, and they come with different operating systems and run different applications — we probably don't need a “Microsoft Surface tablet” tag.

Questions about the Surface tablet should be retagged from [surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface) to [surface-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface-rt) if appropriate — and probably just to [windows8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) (x86) or [windows-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) (ARM), plus [tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablet) if the tablet aspect is relevant.

Comment: I hear Microsoft's legal department is drafting a cease and desist letter to those geometers who continue to abuse their trademark.

Comment: Yeah, about [tag:surface-rt]: out of the only two questions tagged [tag:surface-tablet] one is about the Surface Pro, _not_ Surface RT.

Comment: Just pointing out that [tag:surface-rt] is limited to a single SDK and there's no correct way of referring to the x86 Surface Pro. One could also argue that there should be no questions tagged "Surface as in the product, not an API", just like "iPhone" or "iPad" are bad IMHO

Comment: Surely a tag for `Surface` in terms of geometry for be a burnination candidate as it adds nothing and no one outside of carpentry can really be an expert on surfaces.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Ah, more terminology fragmentation, just what we needed. What tag name(s) and meaning(s) are useful to have about Surface tablets then? Do you mean “none, use [tag:windows-8] or [tag:windows-rt] instead”? Isn't there anything that's common to all tablets running the latest generation of MS OSes?

Comment: @Amicable Uh, what? [tag:surface] is a perfectly cromulent tag in geometry-related topics such as 3D image drawing. Quite useful for searches, and yes, you can be an expert in rendering surfaces.

Comment: For the RT SDK I'd say [tag:windows-rt] is a lot better, as there are _a lot_ of other devices running this ARM-only OS. For the x86 Surface Pro products I don't see why there should ever be a special tag, except for people who write drivers for them. Just like there's no "dell-xps" tag (I hope) there should be no "surface" tag referring to the products. Also, there are _a lot_ of other x86 Surface Pro-like devices. This is in no way the same as Apple having three devices running iOS.

Comment: To prove my point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311788/how-does-windows-8-1-detect-whether-a-machine-is-a-desktop-or-a-tablet - the [tag:surface] tag on this question helps with nothing. There is _absolutely_ nothing different (SDK, OS, APIs) between a Microsoft Surface RT and any other Windows RT device out there.

Comment: You've forgotten about the **Surface Pro**!

Comment: Gotta downvote this, surface-rt is one specific surface product.  This comparable to putting all Nokia phones under the lumia tag.

Comment: @Seth, Sergiu Paraschiv: edited. Given that Surface isn't a series of closely related products, a “Microsoft Surface tablet” tag shouldn't exist at all. Did I miss anything now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Downvote reverted.

Comment: Yup. Seems correct now.

Answer (score 6):

I concur.

Pixelsense is related, but different than Microsoft Surface, and should be its own tag.

`microsoft-surface` should be the master, not `surface`.  If some folks want to comb through the `surface` tag and clean it up, I'll fix the synonyms.

Comment: For other people helping to combing through the [tag:surface] tag: a large proportion of the questions tagged [tag:surface] are actually related to the Android Class [tag:surfaceview]

Comment: I see that a number of questions use "surface" in the geometric sense.  Does anyone agree with the creation of [geometry-surface]?  It seems like an area of expertise that would cross several tools.

Comment: Don't synonymize [tag:surface] to [tag:microsoft-surface]: they're different “Surface” technologies. [tag:surface] gets a lot of use for the common meaning in geometry. @JasonMArcher [tag:geometry-surface] sounds like a bad tag name — nobody says “I want to draw a geometry surface”. [tag:geometric-surface] would be a tad better, but [tag:surface] would be best. Leave [tag:surface] to mean a surface, and [tag:microsoft-surface] (or [tag:surface-rt]?) to mean the tablet. [tag:microsoft-surface] needs to be disconnected from [tag:pixelsense] first.

Comment: We're going to have a major retag operation in year 2200 when androids (like Data) become more popular and people are programming them...

Comment: @gilles: How do you keep people from abusing `surface` to mean `microsoft-surface`?  Do you just give up on that idea?  Sure wish you guys would make up your mind about generic tags.  Another example here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261025 (keyboard, widget, share)

Comment: @Gilles If the tag has more than one meaning, it isn't a good tag.  I chose "geometry-surface" because it follows existing "*geometry*" tags.  It isn't really important, but I went with the existing consensus.

Comment: @Gilles: For another good example, look at the [tag:android] tag cloud.  [tag:activity], [tag:intent], and [tag:layout] were all synonymized to Android terms, because people were typing sentences into the tag editor (despite the fact that all of these terms can mean something else).