# Rename/Disambiguate [ios-app-extension]

Tags: discussion, tags

With the introduction of app extensions in iOS 8, [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) was created. The tag was meant to cover all of the different types of app extensions. The [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1) there are several different types of extensions:

- **Today (iOS and OS X)** - Get a quick update or perform a quick task in the Today view of Notification Center
  (A Today extension is called a widget)
- **Share (iOS and OS X)** - Post to a sharing website or share content with others
- **Action (iOS and OS X)** - Manipulate or view content within the context of another app
- **Photo Editing (iOS)** - Edit a photo or video within the Photos app
- **Finder (OS X)** - Use a remote file storage service in OS X
- **Storage Provider (iOS)** - Choose a document from among the set of documents the current iOS app can access
- **Custom keyboard (iOS)** - Replace the iOS system keyboard with a custom keyboard for use in all apps

[ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) obviously covers all of the iOS extension types, but not the OS X ones. I have not seen any questions related to OS X extensions, but I'd imagine there will eventually be some.

Currently, the majority of the questions in the tag were [tagged by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension?sort=active&pagesize=50), and very few were tagged with [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) when they were first asked. I have seen a few tags that were commonly used for some of the various types:

- [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) for Custom Keyboard extensions
- [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) for Today extensions
- [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) for Share extensions

In my opinion, tags like [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard), [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget), and [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) aren't all that great of tags, and don't tell much about the question.

So should [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) be broken up into tags for each individual extension type? Or should it be renamed?

On another related note, what tag should be used for OS X app extensions?

Comment: IMHO, tags such as [tag:keyboard], [tag:widget] and [tag:share] should probably be treated as auxiliary tags for use with the [tag:ios-app-extension] or other tags; because, who knows, maybe Android will make it possible to make extensions at some point.

Comment: @RobH I didn't know that "auxiliary tags" were a thing. I thought they might qualify as "meta tags".

Comment: That's what I meant. I just forgot the correct term for them when I made the comment.

Comment: @RobH Well meta tags [aren't supposed to exist](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: If it is broken up, what would the tags be called?  Please keep in mind that tags have a 25 character limit, including dashes.

Comment: @Charles I don't know. That was part of my question that I'd like discussed/answered. I thought of the 25 character limit, which limited my ideas.

Comment: How in the world is [ios-app-extension] a meta tag? Seems like to me it would adequately describe the content of a question.

Comment: @CodyGray I was talking about [keyboard], [widget], and [share]. Sorry for the confusion.