# Wouldn't tag inheritance make sense?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-hierarchy

Several times, I wondered if adding a notion of inheritance between tags would be useful. And I think so.

This would majorly make sense with versions. Let's take a few examples:

- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)
- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5)
- [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) and [eclipse-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.2) [eclipse-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.3) [eclipse-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.4) [eclipse-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5) [eclipse-3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5.1) [eclipse-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.6)
- [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and [twitter-bootstrap-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3)
- [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) and [ruby-on-rails-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-2) [ruby-on-rails-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) [ruby-on-rails-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.1) [ruby-on-rails-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2) [ruby-on-rails-3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.2.1) [ruby-on-rails-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) [ruby-on-rails-4.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4.0.2) [ruby-on-rails-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4.1)
- and so on...

When someone open a new question, he/she almost always combine both for visibility, plus a few other tags. This system mainly cause two problems today:

- **Questioner side:** You only have five tags allowed, and must use two of them for the same subject
- **Answerer side:** You must add every "sub-tag" in your favorites to get a full overview of the subject

---

Here's how inheritance could work:

- Add the main tag ([eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)) if your question **is not** version-related (as now)
- Add a sub-tag **only** ([eclipse-3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5.1)) if your question **is** version-related

The system would automatically consider both question as [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) questions, but only the second one as an [eclipse-3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5.1) question.

---

This change doesn't require much work on front-end, maybe just a little visual change: 
Use `eclipse` (3.5.1) instead of `eclipse-3.5.1` to signify its a sub-tag. 
In fact, it would mainly induce modifications in the engine and on tags pages.

What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-hierarchy

Comment: Oh, "hierarchy" word didn't came to my mind when I did my research...

Comment: hierarchy or maybe taxonomy.

Comment: People who know html possibly have no/little idea about html5 and vice versa. Inheritance might clog people's interesting questions lists with questions that they have no knowledge of, because these questions might be very specific to the new/old standard. So you can't just assume they are related.

Comment: @SvenT23 Same comment : this system should only be used for "versioning" tags. If there's too much difference between the main tag and the sub-tags, you'll always monitoring a sub-tag. In the case of [tag:html], every people who learn HTML is able to understand HTML5. And if you don't consider yourself as an HTML5 expert, you should look the [tag:xhtml] tag, I guess ?

Comment: Instead we should just do away with version tags altogether. Why does it matter if you want to use CSS3 transitions; CSS3 is part of CSS. IE11 and IE9 are both IE... yes there are some differences in support, but these should be spelled out inside the post. Tags and titles should draw subject-matter experts to the question, and the content should determine whether they want to/know how to answer or not. No one is a CSS3 expert but not a CSS2 expert, likewise no one is going to be a jQuery 1.9.2 expert but a novice at 1.9.1. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @TylerH: Counter-example (semi-hypothetical): `perl` (meaning Perl 5.x) and `perl6` (meaning the semi-hypothetical Perl 6 language) would be two very different languages. A lot of what applies in Perl 5 would not apply in Perl 6; most of what applies in Perl 6 would not apply to Perl 5.  The dichotomy here is much larger than the gap between Python 2.x and Python 3.x (though that too is substantial).

Comment: Amen.  Tags need inheritance.  They need hierarchy.  For example, I think of html5 as being a shorthand for html/5, or maybe html/html5.  Or html5\html\markup-languages (if you will allow me the use of backslash for reverse path notation).  If there is a sea of tags, it would be nice to have a tree browser for them.  Etc.   This is not just applicable to stackoverflow - it is applicable to almost anything that uses tags. Naming conventions quickly become clunky.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple tag hierarchy to aid in searching / browsing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255245/simple-tag-hierarchy-to-aid-in-searching-browsing)

Comment: What we could use is some built-in prompting to enter additional, more-specific tags when the user has chosen certain combinations of tags . For instance, if the solaris and ksh tags are both there, there is a high probability that we'll need to ask the user which version of Solaris they are asking about, and it would save time if the asker were prompted to enter that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's nothing in the current implementation that precludes the sort of tagging you're talking about.

The big problem is that folks often *have no idea* if their question is version-related or not. If you're using version N and have never used version N-1, then expecting you to know whether the functionality you're asking about applies to version N, version N and N-1, or *all versions* is naive; someone else will have to re-tag it if that is desired. Version tags are best avoided completely in these situations (including the version in the question body isn't a bad idea though).

Comment: You're probably already aware of how misuse of version-specific tags can also create problems for would-be dupehammer wielders depending on the version tag.

Comment: I agree many people don't know if it's version-related or not. That's why I already retag many questions, adding `all-versions` or `n-version` tag for a better visibility. I consider it's my job : I know if it's version-related or not, and I've an access to moderation tools. I don't see any problem to continue this work by replacing one either.

Comment: This! There are some *very specific cases* where version specific tags makes sense, principally when the ABI/API gets mayor changes and both versions keeps getting support, both for all other proposes and aspects they are not necessary almost all the time, which is why I [suggested this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8979/169736) which could be expanded to not suggesting any tags that match `/basename[\d-.]+/` where `basename` is an existing tag.

Answer (score 15):

Why force an inheritance or hierarchy when you have tags?  Maintaining a sensible hierarchy is difficult enough in a tightly controlled environment.  In a distributed system like stack overflow, it would be a mess.

Inheritance/hierarchy implies a many-one relationship of children to parents.  Tagging implies a many-many relationship between children and parents.  While the more common case may be many-one ([css#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%23) being a child of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)), forcing many-one in a distributed system like stack overflow tends to lead to problems.

Instead, allow tags to be meta tagged.

When a tag is given a meta tag (which is just another tag for now), searching for the meta tag, or anything the meta tag is meta tagged, will also find the tag.

So if [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) is tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), searches for [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) would find [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) questions automatically.

Some method to block meta-tag search expansion and only find [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) might be useful.

Cyclic tagging should be allowed (just in case?), but maybe be a sign that what we really have is tag synonyms, but I suspect blocking it would lead to issues.

Synonyms are one-to-one and an equivalent relation, so are not the same thing at all.  [cascading-style-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascading-style-sheets) is a synonym of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), but [css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) is not.

Another non-version example: [Rename/Disambiguate [ios-app-extension]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261025/rename-disambiguate-ios-app-extension) -- [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) should be the parent of many of the app-extension types.

Such a system also opens up the possibility of useful "pure virtual" tags.  Suppose there is a tag that is quite often misused because it is too generic, and we want to encourage sub-tag use.  Mark it as "pure virtual", and when someone uses it they are given a selection of sub-tags (anything directly meta-tagged with it) to choose from.

So we might decide that [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) is rarely a valid tag: instead of burning it, we virtualize it, and add [ios-app-extension-common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension-common) for the few cases where you want to talk about all of the app-extensions at once in the same post (if that is the case).  Askers get better feedback about how to tag, answerers remain able to look at **all** [ios-appextension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-appextension)s if they are experts at all of them.  And the app-extensions that are not ios-app-extensions can be [apple-app-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-app-extensions), which [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension) is also meta tagged with.

Comment: Don't tag synonyms already accomplish what you're describing?  Well, not for CSS3, I guess.  But I claim that CSS3 questions should also be tagged CSS anyway.

Comment: As I read it, they do... but also combine the tags. Yakk seems to be advocating for maintaining distinct `css` and `css3` tags, but adding a mechanism for `css3` tags to show up in a `css` tag search.

Comment: What you're proposing here is a tag hierarchy, you're just calling it something different...

Comment: @RobertHarvy `css3` and `css2` is not synonymous with `css`, but `css3` and `css2` deserve the meta-tag of `css`.  Now suppose something as scary as `css.net` becomes popular: `css.net` would be meta-tagged `css` and `.net` both.

Comment: Yes, meta-tagging tags would be one way to build such a proposed tag hierarchy?!

Comment: @Servy I am distinguishing between heirarchical systems vs tag systems in a way similar to this: http://ruleant.blogspot.ca/2012/09/tag-based-vs-hierarchical-file-system.html -- a tag system is a many-to-many connection, and (I am suggesting above) not even a tree.  Such systems (with fewer rules) can survive distributed editing better than ones with strict constraints sometimes.

Comment: @Yakk Interesting way... I would like to insist on the point that this system should only be used for "versioning" tags. Everyone monitoring [tag:css] will be interested by [tag:css3], but not necessary by [tag:sass].

Comment: See the commentary [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54964358/1275653) I have no opinion as to whether you were right and they were wrong but both cannot be right, can they?

Answer (score 12):

Just use wildcards in your favorites? [css*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css*), [html*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html*), [eclipse*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse*), [twitter-bootstrap*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap*), [ruby-on-rails*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails*), etc.

There are also such tags as [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) and [ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ironpython), so two stars will be better: [*html*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*html*), [*python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*python*).

The only real limitation is the maximum number of tags, you will run into it pretty quickly.
If tag hierarchy would allow to overcome this, it would be good.

Comment: This assumes that the less specific tag is always a prefix of the more specific one. Granted, that is true in every case mentioned so far or that I can readily think of.

Comment: @DavidConrad, [tag:compass-css] and [tag:sass] would be an example.

Comment: compass-css would be caught in a search for `*css*`.

Comment: @zzzzBov more importantly, sass is compiled into normal css, and so is not a CSS version, nor would I want it showing up in my favorites.

Comment: note: [c#*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#*) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @NH. you didn't encode # symbol so it was not recognized as a query parameter. Use `[c#*]` in the search box, it'll give you [the correct url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23*) for the query. Although it returns only `c#` tag itself, probably there are no other tags that start with `c#` currently.

Comment: @user FALSE. There is [tag:c#7]

Comment: @NH. Indeed, I see, there are also [tag:c#-7.0] and [tag:c#-pattern-matching]. Then you may want to report a bug. A question on meta tagged [bug] should do.

Comment: @user, looks like someone [already did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270315/364344). Go vote for it.