# Same tags with different version numbers

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a suggested use of tagging a question with the same tag but with different version numbers?

For instance, if I want to tag my question with Xcode 5.1 should I use both the `xcode` and `xcode5` tags or just `xcode5`?

Another example would be tagging with `css` and `css3` for a CSS3 question.  Is this redundant?

Comment: For Python I always add the generic tag if it is missing. [tag:python-3.x] is valuable info, but there are simply far more people watching the [tag:python] tag.

Comment: Not the same question, but this recent question is related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense/.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends.

You get a much larger audience by tagging both (as all those watching just CSS will see it). If it is not necessarily specific to a version, definitely tag both.

If it **only** applies to Xcode 5.1 and not to general Xcode than you should probably only tag the specific one.

That being said, I doubt you will hurt anyones feelings by tagging both, and I would do so myself if I wasn't sure if it was a version-specific question or not.