# Should there generally be only one tag for a language, rather than multiple (especially minor) versions?

Tags: discussion, tags, language-versions

I see, for example:

- [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)
- [perl4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl4)
- [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5)
- [perl5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.6)
- [perl5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.8)
- [perl5.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.10)
- [perl5.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.12)
- [perl5.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.14)
- [perl5.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.18)
- [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6)

Many of these have only a couple of questions tagged with them. Should only the main one be used? Does it depend on how many questions are associated with them, or should the general rule of thumb be that there should be one tag for a language?

I can see that, perhaps, one might want to know "this is a Perl 5.18 question, so I will answer it differently from a Perl5.14 question". But couldn't this be handled without tags, such as by stating the version at the beginning of the question?

*(Note that there might reasonably be tags for distinct aspects/modules/packages for languages, such as [bioperl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioperl). That seems different from the issue of language **version**.)*

Comment: FYI: the main tag should **always** be used. If you want to specify a version you then **add** the version-specific tag. So a question specific to perl5.8 should be tagged [tag:perl] and [tag:perl5.8]. This is true for frameworks-related tags too (e.g. [tag:angular.js] and things like that should *also* be tagged [tag:javascript]). Why? 1) Proper language highlighting 2) The main language tag is most often the only one with many followers, so not using it means you are losing a lot of potential answerers 3) If your question is a duplicate it will be closed much more easily via dupe-hammer

Comment: In a similar vein, should all C++11/C++14/etc questions also be tagged C++? Was going to ask a similar question on here when I found this one.

Comment: Version specific tags, while semi-useful, aren't... entirely useful. Someone that can answer a java tag in 1.8 might be able to answer is in 1.4 and vice versa. Many times the tags hurt visibility for someone following a tag - they end up following 20 tags and clicking around

Comment: The solution to this is [tag inheritance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262823/1739000), aka [tag heirarchy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223400/364344), but in the mean time, I agree with @Bakuriu that we should tag with the main language tag as well.

Answer (score 21):

Generally speaking, version-specific tags should only exist when:

- There are major backwards-incompatible differences between versions, **and**
- Both versions of the software continue to be used by the developer community.

In essence, there should be questions regularly asked about both versions, with significantly different answers depending on which version.

---

In the case of Perl, most of these tags should not exist.

[perl4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl4) refers to a version of the language that has been obsolete since 1994. While it passes the first test, as Perl 5 introduced a lot of major new features that didn't exist in Perl 4, it completely fails the second test: there is effectively no Perl 4 developer community in existence. There have only ever been two questions created with this tag in the history of this site, both from users who have the misfortune to be working on extremely old systems.

[perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) is essentially synonymous with [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) in common usage, as it is the only major version of Perl regularly used by developers. As I am not a moderator, I cannot suggest that they be set up as synonyms; I would appreciate it if someone with the appropriate rights could do that!

Tags for revisions of Perl 5 (e.g, [perl5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.8), [perl5.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.10), etc) fail the first test: the differences between these versions are relatively minor. Changes which break backwards incompatibility are rare, and usually involve the deprecation of long-obsolete features. As such, these tags should be merged to the parent [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) tag. Most of the questions tagged with them are either asking questions about code which is running on that version of Perl, or are asking questions about new features introduced in a particular version. The former are typically not specific to the version at all, and the latter are typically equally applicable to any later version: an answer explaining a feature introduced in Perl 5.10 will usually also apply to 5.12 or later.

[perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) should stay. Perl 6 is a completely separate language from Perl 5; it's related to Perl 5 in the same sort of way that C++ is related to C. Questions tagged as [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) should generally *not* be tagged as [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) unless they're specifically asking about converting or bridging between the two.

Comment: What would happen when Perl 6 is the norm?

Comment: *"Tags for revisions of Perl 5 ... fail the first test: the differences between these versions are relatively minor"* Apart from that being a value judgement, can you substantiate it in any way? From your record on SO you don't seem to be particularly familiar with Perl, and as I describe in my answer, it has undergone significant changes that would have brought about a major version increment in other languages. Perl 5 cannot follow suit because of the pre-existence of Perl 6

Comment: @Braiam At this point, that appears unlikely to ever happen. Perl 6 has diverged from Perl 5 to the point that both languages will likely coexist forever.

Comment: @Borodin I haven't been particularly active in answering Perl questions here, but I'm very familiar with the language. With regard to Perl versions: the changes made in Perl 5.8, 5.10, etc. are generally evolutionary, and typically only introduce new features or extend existing ones. It's rare that a new Perl version will invalidate existing, well-written code.

Comment: @Borodin Moreover, keep in mind that Stack Overflow uses the metric that tags should represent distinct things that someone might specifically be an expert with. This isn't true of Perl versions; a person wouldn't be a Perl 5.10 expert but be unfamiliar with Perl 5.8, for instance.

Comment: "a person wouldn't be a Perl 5.10 expert but be unfamiliar with Perl 5.8, for instance" that seems very unlikely. For example, I know JS, Python and some Ruby, once I'm working with a new version I adapt to it, like a good programmer that tries that his code runs on everything it's run.

Comment: -1 -- The fact that a version is "obsolete" shouldn't count to remove its tag. It's always possible to ask questions about old technology, so I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: @Bakuriu It's not just the fact that it's obsolete, but that it's so rarely used anymore that there are essentially no questions about it. (Two questions, both asked by the same person around six years ago.)

Comment: "*asking questions about new features introduced in a particular version*" - granted, I don't know how many features Perl versions do introduce, but this seems like a viable reason to use a tag. They don't have to be backwards-incompatible, they just have to add significantly to the language.

Comment: I was stuck on 5.8 for a long time, and never really did much after finally having access to 5.10, but it struck me that writing code that had to support Perl 5.8 or later was much trickier than code that only had to support 5.10 or later. (It had to do more with available libraries than the language itself, though.)

Answer (score 10):

Whatever the answer to your question may be, working your way through the Stack Overflow archive removing tags from questions isn't a responsible or useful thing to do. I would agree that, if a question is tagged *only* with a specific version of a language then it also should carry the general version tag, but the additional more specific tag is certainly doing no harm, and can usually be useful for some purposes

The case of Perl may be slightly different from other languages, because recent releases of Perl 5 have taken the opportunity to incorporate some useful ideas from the Perl 6 project, and these have occasionally been very significant. Built-in Unicode support has also taken huge strides forwards

The most significant release in my opinion have been versions 5.8, 5.10 and 5.14. That is not to say that there haven't been major alterations in other versions, but for the purposes of this question I am considering only the most effective differences

Version 5.8 is significant in part because it is *binary incompatible* with previous versions. This is the only place where backward-incompatibility is relevant, as Perl 5 continues to be able to run the vast majority of programs that were executable under 5.0. This version also implemented the first major Unicode overhaul and a new Perl IO susbsystem

Version 5.10 added the `feature` pragma as well as the `switch` feature, which added language words `given`, `when`, and `default` and the smart-match operator `~~`. `state` variables are new, and there are many significant enhancements to the regular expression syntax

Version 5.14 added non-destructive operation of `s///` and `tr///`, as well as support for Unicode 6 and IPv6

These are only the major changes that come to mind. Of course there are countless more less noticeable ones, and many bug fixes and optimisations

Perl is in the unfortunate position where, because of the existence of the Perl 6 project, it must continue to increment its minor version even when major changes are made to the language. It is also in the nature of Perl that, partly because it doesn't have a prescribed syntax tree, it is much more straightforward to add language features than it would be for more tightly-defined designs

In summary, my answer to your question is that it is very dependent on the subject matter whether versioned topic tags are useful of not. But as long as a question carries the unversioned tag as well, any number of versioned ones can be added without any detriment, and you are doing no one a service by starting a one-man crusade to remove versioned tags wholesale

Comment: I generally agree, with the provision that the summary advice really applies only to someone without 2k editing. Otherwise, you seem to be suggesting that version tags can *never* need burninating, which I think is wrong, and certainly needs a great deal more rationale to accept.

Answer (score 4):

> Tags are keywords or labels that categorize and group your question with other, similar questions.

Having only one tag would crowd one tag too much, and people interested in just a newer version of language would have to come across all those useless (for them) questions. Different version of languages have many changes, and sometimes different enough that a person familiar with an older version finds it difficult to cope up with a newer version (consider, HTML 4 and 5).

So, there shouldn't be only one tag for a language.

Comment: The key is also that there should be a significant difference. (like I understand is true for python2 and python3.). It depends on the users of that tag if perl5.14 is really that much different from perl5.12 that a version tag is needed. if perl5 will do those minor version tags are better burniated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there isn't one universal rule to manage specific version/minor tags because it heavily *depends* on the versioning scheme (if any) used from the sofware/language author[s].

Without a versioning scheme, every version of the software could contains breaking changes. So it's possible that something true (e.g. a documented behaviour) for 1.0.1, became false in 1.0.2. With software like these we're *doomed to the tag-hell*: only the work of the community can prevent this, doing an evaluation on a case by case basis (the perl case analyzed by duskwuff is a good example).

With a clear and unambiguous versioning scheme, like [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), these problems *should* be mitigated. If I ask a question about 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3..., this is always a question about 1.0: in the details (description) I'll add the specific version (e.g. 1.0.3) to help others understand if it's a problem related to 1.0.3 or not. So, in this case, only `software`, `software-X`, `software-X.Y` tags should be used if necessary. Even in this case, the community role isn't replaceable.

Fortunately the semantic versioning scheme is being adopted from many and many projects (not only opensource). For an interesting example see the differences of the [groovy versioning scheme pre and post 2.0](https://www.grails.org/versioning.html).