# Shouldn't older version tags be merged into original when a newer version of language is out?

Tags: discussion, tags, language-versions

I have seen many questions in Swift language which are supported for many versions of the language but are tagged specifically for single version (like swift2 or swift 1.2). I usually edit their tags to include all but swift has been changing very fast and another version is comes every quarter and there may be a new tag for it.

According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299598/should-there-generally-be-only-one-tag-for-a-language-rather-than-multiple-esp), version tags should be added along with main language tag. But a solution in swift may work for 4 versions and you can't tag all of them. Shouldn't older tags be merged into original when a newer version is out? Like `Swift 1.1` and `Swift 1.2` be merged into `Swift` since there are `swift 2.0` and `swift 2.1` on market, since most developers have to shift to latest version quickly (unlike other languages like `ruby on rails` or `perl`.)

Comment: `But a solution in swift may work for 4 versions and you can't tag all of them.`: only two tags max wil be used at the same time, the main `swift` tag + *one* other tag being the version used by OP if the code is specific to an older version than the currently shipped one.

Comment: I'm confused: this seems to be about tagging solutions. where exactly do you tag solutions? I only see tags on questions, and questions tend to be about one or at most two versions of a particular product or service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

What if you're stuck using an older version of a library / language?

The required answer may be specific to that version.

---

As quoted from that [linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299613/1835379):

> Generally speaking, version-specific tags should only exist when:
>
> - There are major backwards-incompatible differences between versions, **and**
> - Both versions of the software continue to be used by the developer community.

In essence, there should be questions regularly asked about both versions, with significantly different answers depending on which version.

Comment: I specifically asked about Swift type languages where people have to shift towards latest language almost every time hence `Both versions of the software continue to be used by the developer community` fails.

Answer (score 4):

**People use language version tags for various purposes.** Often they use the latest version tag to mean: I need modern language features. (I think that's the most common case.)

But a specific language version tag can also be used to mean: "***that version and exactly that version***". We can't dismiss that occurrence (even if it might be a rare case) *and we can't afford to lose that information* by systematically altering tags without attention to context.