# Make [perl5] an alias for [perl]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) is the accepted tag for the Perl 5 programming language, and [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) is the accepted tag for the Perl 6 programming language. (See [Should [perl6] questions be tagged with the [perl] tag as well?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315419/589924)) These are two different programming languages (like C and C#).

**This leaves the [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) tag largely unused and synonymous for [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl).**

Questions tagged [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl): 63,163
Questions tagged [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5): 138

[Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5+-perl) tagged [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5), but not tagged [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl): 21, all of which should be tagged [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl).

The [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) tag has no wiki.

**I propose making the [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) tag an alias of [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl).**

I request this because someone might use [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) instead of [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) and not get suitable visibility. This happened last month, for example.

Note that [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) isn't used to identify a specific version of the language or interpreter.<sup>[1]</sup> When such a need arises, people have been known to use tags of the form [perl5.30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.30). As such, merging the tags doesn't result in any loss of information.

However, most Perl users don't call it Perl 5. Its name was historically just "Perl", the interpreter is named `perl`, and even the official site refers it to ["Perl"](https://www.perl.org/about/style-guide.html) on occasion. So making [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5) an alias of [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) is probably a better approach than making [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) an alias of [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5).

---

1. The 5 hasn't been considered a version since at least 2000, and the existence of Perl 6 prevents it from ever being considered one again.

   ```
   $ perl -v | grep ^This
   This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

   $ man perl | head -n 4 | tail -n 1
          perl - The Perl 5 language interpreter
   ```