# Organize wildfly tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found a little bit misleading following tags:

- [wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly)
- [wildfly-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-8)
- [wildfly-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-9)
- [wildfly-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-10)
- [wildfly-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-11)
- [wildfly-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-12)
- [wildfly-13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly-13)

I mean are we using a tag for every wildfly versions ? For example for 14,15,16,etc.. without end ? There is a guideline for this?

I ask this because: or we using tag with version (and migrate wildfly tags to corresponding version) or without, mixing them is only confusing, at least for me

Reference: [Should there generally be only one tag for a language, rather than multiple (especially minor) versions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299598/should-there-generally-be-only-one-tag-for-a-language-rather-than-multiple-esp/299613#299613)

Comment: I like version-specific tags myself, they help set a proper timeframe for a question. A question asked about Wildfly 8 is not necessarily relevant for Wildfly 13.

Comment: [The linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299613) already provides an adequate answer to this question. There are good reasons for version-specific language tags, but they should be used only when they are actually necessary (i.e., the problem is version-specific), and they should always be combined with a "master" tag (the one that isn't version-specific). So that covers that. If your question is how to clean up the existing Wildfly tag usage, you'll need a subject expert to weigh in on that discussion.

Comment: Thanks Gimby and Cody, for me these answer should could be closed. Let's use version specific tags for wildfly versions

Comment: I removed the [tag:tag-disambiguation] tag, as the question seemed like asking guidance on what to do in general, rather than disambiguating this particular set. Also, given that you were convinced with the argument in the other question, I have now closed it as a duplicate of that one. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, it's fine for me