# Dupehammer powerless against tags with versions

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, language-versions

Last week I was trying to close a question as a duplicate using my [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) gold badge powers and I was surprised that only 1 close vote was recorded and the question was not closed immediately.

Only later I have realised that the question was actually tagged [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2). Usage of this tag was not incorrect, the question was written in Swift 2 but the problem already had a Swift (Swift1) canonical answer.

I have added [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) to the question and I understand why I couldn't close the it using dupehammer but I wonder whether there is something we can do about tags with versions.

**To give you some examples:**

- nobody currently has [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2) gold badge, there are multiple questions which are not tagged [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), there is also [swift2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2.1) and new version (3.0) will appear next year.
- there are multiple questions tagged [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) or [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) but without [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), rendering `Java` gold badge users helpless (there is no user with those badges).
- there are multiple questions tagged [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.5) or [.net-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) without corresponding [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tags. Jon Skeet is the only user who has those badges with versions.
- there are multiple [oracle11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle11g) questions but without tag [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)

**Why is this important?**

When a new version of a language/framework is released, most of the functionality stays the same, therefore most questions and answers are still valid.

**Possible solutions**

1. Do nothing - the gold badge user will have to wait for another user to add the "main" tag or we will just use the 5-votes-to-close system.
2. (feature request) - create new relationships between tags, other than synonyms, e.g. [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) would be in parent-child relationship with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). All [java-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-7) would be also automatically tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Note this would also improve search.
3. (workaround) - enable gold badge users also to close questions tagged by a regular expression created from the badge, e.g. `[badge-\d]`. Note that creation of such regular expression would be tricky.

Comment: 4. Ask someone in chat to add the generic language tag to the question for you, and then dupe-hammer it.

Comment: 5. No, seriously, do nothing, as this isn't much of a problem at all.

Comment: More good arguments to avoid using version tags...

Comment: Check this out also [Wouldn't tag inheritance make sense?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262823)

Comment: You are right that is a duplicate.