# Tag synonyms that create 2 tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

This is different request than (bigger/complicate) [Tag inheritance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense):

> Here's how inheritance could work :
>
> Add the main tag (eclipse) if your question is not version-related (as now)
>
> Add a sub-tag only (eclipse-3.5.1) if your question is version-related

I don't want to differentiate tags as main or sub-tag, only additional tag relationship which is **enforced**.

Sometimes tags are connected inherently, I suggest an option/request similar to Tag synonyms:

Tag will be connected to different (relevant) tag **always**, meaning:

I want tag, for example jmeter-3.2, to always create jmeter-3.2 tag and **add** additional jmeter tag.

It's a win-win situation: people who search jmeter will find also find jmeter-3.2 related Q&A and people who ask about jmeter-3.2 won't be ignored by people search by jmeter

Comment: It's similar issue but different request