# We’ve made changes to our Privacy Notice for Collectives™

Tags: discussion, collectives, legal, privacy

We’ve just made a few adjustments to our [Privacy Notice for Collectives™](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy/collectives). They were made to make the notice ready for the upcoming [expansion of Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/collectives-the-next-iteration) into new areas of practice - as well as streamline and make some points clearer. There isn't a *ton* of impact to users here or significant departures from how we're already doing things.

---

1. We've swapped the order of the "ABOUT THE COLLECTIVES™ PRIVACY NOTICE" and "ABOUT COLLECTIVES™ ON STACK OVERFLOW" sections.
2. We've made the following changes in the "ABOUT THE COLLECTIVES™ PRIVACY NOTICE" section:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Used to read: | This Privacy Notice is applicable to you when you interact with us through our product Collectives™ on Stack Overflow ("Collectives"). |
| Now reads: | This Privacy Notice is applicable to you when you interact with us through our Collectives™ ("Collectives") on StackOverflow.com (“Stack Overflow”). |
| Used to read: | Here you will find details about the personal information we collect about you when you interact with us on Collectives, how and why we collect it, how we use it, and how we keep it secure. This Privacy Notice also tells you about your rights, how you can exercise those rights, and how the law protects you. |
| Now reads: | Here you will find details about who is responsible for managing the personal information we collect about you when you interact with us on Collectives, our legal basis for doing so (as applicable), and what additional purposes the personal information will be used for and by whom. For all other descriptions of how Stack Overflow collects, uses, protects, shares, and transfers information about you that we collect when you use Collectives or any other of our products and services, websites, or apps or otherwise interact with us, as well as your rights, how you can exercise those rights, and how the law protects you, see our Stack Exchange Privacy Policy. |
| Used to read: | If you have any questions about this Privacy Notice or the way we use your personal data, please contact us at privacy@stackoverflow.com |
| Now reads: | If you have any questions about this Privacy Notice, the Stack Exchange Privacy Policy, or other questions related to the way we process/use your personal information, please contact us at privacy@stackoverflow.com. |

3. We've made the following changes in the "ABOUT COLLECTIVES™ ON STACK OVERFLOW" section:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Used to read: | Collectives™ on Stack Overflow is a grouping of content around a set of products, services and/or technologies. It is a grouping of content based on tags, and together forms a home for an organization or topic on Stack Overflow. It’s a place for users to discover content related to those tags, both Q&A and content that goes beyond regular Q&A, such as Articles. Collectives can also recognize users with specific permissions, such as posting articles within a Collective, recommending answers that are associated with a Collective and having a user badge that highlights the user’s association with the Collective. Users must be logged in to join or participate in Collectives. It is subject to the Collectives Terms of Use. |
| Now reads: | Collectives™ on Stack Overflow is a grouping of content around a set of products, services, and/or technologies based on tags, forming dedicated spaces for a provider or area of expertise on Stack Overflow. Defined by tags, a collective brings developers together to collaborate and learn from one another, as well as connect with subject matter experts from the community and the organizations that help build or maintain a technology product/service. Content includes questions and answers and other content, such as technical Articles authored by Members of a collective, and Bulletins – timely, useful, and relevant updates published by Admins of a collective. Users must be logged in to join or participate in Collectives. |
| Used to read: | Stack Overflow has partnered with technology organizations (Companies) to enable them to participate in Collectives. We have used the terms technology organizations and Customers interchangeably throughout this notice. |
| Now reads: | For the provider Collectives, Stack Overflow has partnered with third-party partner technology providers who aggregate content around specific tags related to the provider's technology and develop Articles or other long-form content. |

4. We've removed an entire section called "WHO IS THE CONTROLLER?" because that is now folded in the a new section called "LEGAL BASIS" that has been added.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Used to read: | Stack Exchange, Inc. is the controller responsible for your personal data when you use and access Collectives. Technology organizations (Stack’s Customer) may also act as controller in certain circumstances, such as where it uses any personal data it has collected for its own purposes. Our technology organizations are able to perform certain activities on the same data set (assigning badges, etc.) for its own purposes. When they do this, data protection laws deem that they are joint controllers in respect of the personal information. We have entered into contracts with our Customers, as well as our vendors/subprocessors, to ensure that your personal data is processed in accordance with applicable laws. In addition to this privacy notice, you should review privacy notices of the participating organizations with Collectives pages on Stack Overflow. We and the organization with a Collective may be joint controllers in relation to some activities. |
| Now reads: | If you are a resident of the EEA, UK, or Switzerland, Stack Exchange, Inc. (“Stack Exchange”) is the data controller responsible for your personal information when you use and access Collectives. Technology providers (Stack Exchange’s customers) may also act as controller in certain circumstances on provider Collectives, such as where it uses any personal information it has collected for its own purposes. Additionally, providers are able to perform certain activities on the same data set on Collectives data (e.g., assigning badges) for its own purposes. As such, we have entered into appropriate agreements with those providers, as well as applicable service providers/subprocessors, to ensure that your personal information is processed in accordance with applicable data protection laws. In addition to this privacy notice, you are encouraged to review privacy notices of the participating organizations with provider Collectives pages on Stack Overflow. |

5. We've removed an entire section called "WHAT WE USE YOUR PERSONAL DATA FOR (PURPOSES)" because it was replaced by a new section "WHAT WE USE YOUR PERSONAL INFORMATION FOR" that has been added. This has a more precise definition of what the provider will use "your username", rather than generally calling out "your personal data".

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Used to read: | We will use your personal data as described in our General Privacy Notice. In addition, we will use it for the following additional purposes in connection with the Collectives product. We will use it to manage the Collectives product, and to provide you with any products and services you requested. Our Customer will use your personal data (e.g., your username) to assign badges/roles for their own purposes on the basis of their legitimate interests. Our Customer will use your personal information to assign you badges, tags and to nominate users. |
| Now reads: | We will use your personal information as described in our [Stack Exchange Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy). In addition, we will use certain personal information for the following additional purposes in connection with any provider Collectives: 1) We will use it to manage any provider Collectives product, and to provide you with any products and services you requested. 2) Providers will use your username to assign badges/roles for their own purposes on the basis of their legitimate interests. |

6. We've removed entire sections called "WHO DO WE SHARE YOUR PERSONAL INFORMATION WITH?", "HOW LONG WILL WE RETAIN YOUR PERSONAL INFORMATION FOR?", "YOUR DATA PROTECTION RIGHTS", "WHERE WE PROCESS YOUR INFORMATION (LOCATIONS)", "INTERNATIONAL DATA TRANSFERS", "OUR ONGOING COMMITMENT TO DATA SECURITY", "COMPLAINTS", and "HOW WE MAY CONTACT YOU" because they simply pointed to the [Stack Exchange Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) which we've already covered in the "ABOUT THE COLLECTIVES™ PRIVACY NOTICE" above.

---

Overall these changes streamline the policy, make it easier to read and understand what we share on top of what the Privacy Policy calls out (your username), and makes it clear that this only happens for "Provider Collectives"; i.e., we aren't transferring any personal information other than publicly accessible usernames to partners in Provider Collectives.

Comment: The first change in #3, seems to be going from an accurate description of what collectives are, to the marketing spin that claims collectives "brings developers together to collaborate and learn from one another, as well as connect with subject matter experts from the community and the organizations that help build or maintain a technology product/service", none of which it actually does.

Comment: @KevinB How so? I see all those points in the Google Cloud collective tbh.

Comment: @Stranger *all* of these points existed before collectives were released. They will continue to exist when the collective is gone. The collective isn't what created this environment

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, you do have a point.