# Add the [codemagic] tag to the CI/CD Collective

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, cicd-collective

I'd like to suggest a new tag [codemagic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codemagic) to be added to [the CI/CD category](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423429/launching-the-ci-cd-and-r-collectives-and-community-editing-features-for-article)

Comment: For the record, you're in the right place to suggest adding it.  The request might benefit from a little more explanation, though.

Comment: @RyanM the tag description claims that codemagic is a CI/CD tool, so it seems like a pretty natural fit.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do generally agree with that, which makes the voting on this question otherwise somewhat puzzling to me, so I decided to speculate a bit.  If anyone doesn't like this request, an explanation of the issues with it would be welcome.

Comment: Well, @RyanM, I guess one explanation could be as follows. "I'd like to suggest  X but I don't know how to suggest  X" - is that a suggestion of X, or a request for details of how to suggest X? The (poor) title suggests the former, but the question the latter. And in general "I'd like to suggest that someone does X" as a way of phrasing "Please do X" just opens up the natural response of "Sure, feel free to make that suggestion", especially when there's ambiguity as to whether the question is actually about difficulty making the suggestion.

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion here... please add "Codemagic" tag to the CI/CD Collective

Comment: I also don't think it's outside the realm of possibility that the general community sentiment towards Collectives could be influencing the voting here to some degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag has been added to the collective.

Answer (score 4):

After [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/discussions/77017830/tag-addition-post-on-meta-for-codemagic) within the CI/CD collectives, the consensus is "Accepted".

It does fit the collective.

Comment: thanks and when can we expect the tag be added? currently it's still not there