# Create Collective for JavaScript, or browser tech in general

Tags: feature-request, collectives

Currently, it's not possible to create an article about anything browser related because every article must belong to a corresponding collective.

Can new collectives only be created by large organizations like Google or Amazon? There are some non-sponsored [collectives like R language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423429/launching-the-ci-cd-and-r-collectives-and-community-editing-features-for-article) [or PHP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425532/launching-2-new-collectives-php-and-nlp), so I'd like to see a general collective like "JavaScript" or "Browser programming" so it could also include articles about TypeScript, WebAssembly, WebGL/WebGPU, etc.

Comment: A crucial part of a feature request is _"Why"_. How does this improve SO? What's the benefit? Why should this collective be created?

Comment: Related: [Collectives: The next iteration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422971/2821954). Note that only staff can create and manage Collectives.

Comment: Bear in mind that at least part of the negative reaction you may get to the idea, is that a non-insignificant part of the "meta-crowd", such as it is, is not particularly on board with the whole "collectives" feature.

Comment: @Cerbrus to provide space for articles about browser-related tech

Comment: @yivi I noticed :)

Comment: Don't answer me in the comments, edit your feature request to include that...

Comment: @Cerbrus it is already included at the end

Comment: What content do you envision being in such Articles? Why can't that content be in question and answer format? Basically, you've said you want a Collective, so there can be Articles, but made no case here that there's anything to go in Articles which can't be adequately covered in question and answer format.

Comment: That doesn't answer the _"Why"_... That's _"what"_ you're requesting.

Comment: @Makyen What you’re requesting, is reasoning for the articles feature to exist in the first place; that’s not really fair to demand from this feature request, which is simply to detach them from Collectives, and make them open to everything. Although, the reason you’re asking, is probably because the justification for articles being a feature within Collectives, is rather bad, and that we’ve seen little to no useful usage of them.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact You've mischaracterized what this feature request is asking for. This feature request doesn't ask for detaching Articles from Collectives and having articles generally available. It asks for the creation of a specific Collective in order to allow Articles about a specific topic, but doesn't show any reason why Articles about that specific subject should exist or why the existing Q&A format can't cover that need. As such, I feel it's quite reasonable to ask for the OP to explain what sorts of things might be in those Articles which aren't possible to cover in Q&A.

Comment: it's an X/Y question, so it's going to draw answers to both the root question and the one actually asked.

Comment: @Makyen Sure; the first paragraph still seems like a request to detach them from the collectives, though. Although, you should rather ask for reasoning of why an entire new collective is needed, and not just the articles, because a collective is more (useless stuff) than just articles, and the justification for articles doesn’t justify a whole collective.

Comment: You have nothing to worry about. Everything will be added to a collective, eventually. That's just what the Borg do.

Comment: I have no idea what the value prop of collectives is for actual users, other than to generate money to keep the lights on for Q&A, which is the entire point of Stack Exchange to me.

Answer (score 7):

A collective for "browser tech in general" would be quite the mess given it'd have to be limited to effectively, css/html and couldn't include the tags you're  wanting to write/see articles for.

One for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) would similarly be quite broad, moreso than even the existing php collective in that it's both client and server-side and further branches out into typescript, the various frameworks, etc. A collective in this case wouldn't really serve a purpose, the content "collected" within it would not be helped by being a part of a collective.

I could see an argument for articles being disconnected from collectives, however thus far it seems the article feature is fairly poor at attracting views. I'm not quite sure why one would want to post articles there, unless they literally had no other place to post it or just wanted another place to post it.

Comment: Good points why Collectives (TM) are so flawed to begin with. They assume that the technologies are all confined to a certain group, while in reality, there are no specific dividing lines between them. The limits are gradual. Technologies used for one thing, are also used for another. Collectives (TM) fail to represent the reality.

Comment: Maybe articles should be free like regular SO questions and just have tags instead of categories(Collectives)

Comment: @Pawel I do think that'd generally be a good thing for the articles feature, though I suspect it'd need to be gated somehow to avoid "lost souls" accidentally asking questions there.