# Why was this off-topic question about port forwarding in Kubernetes/Minikube reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77922378/5468463), "*Enabling Dual-Protocol (TCP and UDP) Port Forwarding on the Same Port in Kubernetes with Minikube*", was closed and then reopened.
It was deleted and undeleted and have a reopen vote.

I close voted as off-topic, because it is not a programming question. It is not linked to a programming problem.

On top of that there are at least 3 questions, so it is not even focused.

In my opinion the question is DevOps and is not about programming.

I saw that it went twice thru the reopening, one via the queue and one outside.

Can someone explain why it was re-reopened and how it is on-topic or a legit SO question?

Comment: What is our stance on Docker? Isn't that a tool often used by programmers in a programing context? Isn't k8s in the same realm?

Comment: Tag wiki. For reference: “KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK.” (not that the tag wiki is necessarily the rule of law, :shrug:)

Comment: I don't really see why we don't consider K8s manifest files as programming. K8s manifest files as far as I see are a form of declarative programming.

Comment: What kind of k8 question would be considered configuration if we’re going to just consider the config files a form of “programming”? How does that translate to other forms of configuration that are currently considered off topic?

Comment: To draw a parallel again with docker as @rene commented we also have the [tag:docker-compose] tag, which is somewhat similar to K8s manifests. Do we consider docker compose as off-topic?

Comment: To be fair, I am a bit tired of seeing all those off topic questions. But it was inevitable since CI/CD collective was introduced. If only there would be some other site where such questions would be on topic. Maybe we could call it https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnSmith the issue is not about how well or not the question is written, the issue is that it is off topic question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The question is about configuring Minikube, which is a development tool. Development tools are on topic which is why we have so many rtfm help-me-configure-my-IDE questions. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @Ruddy no it is not a tool for programming from what I read https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/. Not everything around programming is a programming tool

Comment: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/docker_desktop_replacement/ It is if you use it as a docker desktop replacement like my org does.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That "if" is what doesn't make it a development tool, it only means it *can* be used as one. Many developers use coffee machines, but that doesn't make them *specific* to programming.

Comment: That question is now deleted (not just closed). Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Ok, I'll bite. Why do we have a CI/CD collective on SO if we have a devops stack exchange? Should we vote to close on SO questions that are a better fit for the devops site? That would kind of put the CI/CD collective out of business.

Comment: Because something is a better "fit" on a different site in the community isn't a closure reason, @PresidentJamesK.Polk . There are (a lot of) subjects that are on-topic on multiple sites in the community. My opinion on the CI/CD collective, however, is that things in that tag were a little "muddy" already on what was appropriate on [main], and the collective has made it *appear* less muddy, even though actually no guidelines have changed. In truth, the community probably *should* have been made on [devops.se], but the feature doesn't exist there, so it was created in the *wrong* place.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Having CI/CD collective on SO was a bad idea in the first place. Most of those questions are off topic here as they deal with configurations of non programming tools and other stuff that are not directly related to programming.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/collectives-the-next-iteration#comment945509_422971

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Because other sites don't support collectives yet, so everything gets lumped into SO, the company's golden child.

Comment: Yeah what is the truth? If you look at the [help center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it specifically dictates that a question needs to be programming problem in how it (poorly) formulates it. But if you look at the close reason description, it reads *"Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers."* - this one allows a whole lot more. Conflicting and poorly written documentation, differing interpretations of the rules will be the consequence.

Comment: Voted to undelete. Way too harsh to delete something which has quality content.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I fully support that. In the good old days there was this notion of "we do not delete value". That needs to make a comeback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can someone explain why it was reopened and how it is on-topic or a legit SO question?

It was likely reopened because three users felt it *was* on-topic. Personally, I disagree with that viewpoint; the question is not related to programming.

The question has subsequently been re-closed and also deleted.

Comment: Deleted? Should it not have been migrated?

Comment: @Clonkex Migration's harder than it looks. Deliberately. Some communities got real mad being used as a dumping ground for questions too crappy for SO.

Comment: @Clonkex Migration requires all three users choose the same migration option. It's also only possible for users to migrate questions to one of 4 or so sites... I don't think DevOps is one of them. Moderators could migrate any question manually, but they are loathe to do that, as there's no guarantee a question will be well-received on the target site, and they like to have a mod on the target site review the request and agree before doing so.

Comment: Does the answerer get to keep the bounty?

Comment: @SalmanA Once bounty rep is awarded it is not removed even if the post is deleted. I'm not sure whether the bounty record itself would transfer over during migration, but I think not, because the post on the new site relies on a separate account (with separate reputation).

Comment: @TylerH It looks like [bounty reputation does get reversed upon deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243438/1024093). Or maybe that's only for mod-deletion?

Comment: @tdy Oh, thanks. Though that is from 2014, so there's a chance it could have changed since then. But good find!

Comment: And deleted again, and already a vote away from undeletion. Add in a shopping mall and we've got a good zombie movie.

Comment: the question now takes a moderator to undelete. feel free to flag for undeletion in case a consensus in that direction is eventually established